# What is Ruby IO text file mode 't' for?

Tags: ruby

The documentation of [IO ruby class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-c-new) says that a mode "t" named "text file mode" exists.

I didn't find the differences between "t" mode and a more general "r" mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Operating Systems distinguish between text files and binary files (most notably Windows), others don't (most "Unix-ish" OSs).

On OSs that don't distinguish between text and binary files, the two modes are identical.

On Windows, opening a file in text mode will perform EOL conversion, and *might* also perform character transcoding.